# How to fix Makefile syntax error when using wildcard on make clean?

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, wildcard

I have a simple Makefile that just contains this one target. It looks like this:

```
SHELL:=/bin/bash

clean:
    rm !(*.tex|Makefile|*.pdf)
```

When I run this command in bash it works fine, i.e. it gives no errors and it removes the desired files. However when I run `make clean` it gives the following errors:

```
$ make clean
rm !(*.tex|Makefile|*.pdf)
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `rm !(*.tex|Makefile|*.pdf)'
make: *** [clean] Error 1
```

Has anybody got an idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Nice syntax to clean out everything but the Makefile itself, the latex source and any resulting pdf's.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change the `SHELL` line to

```
SHELL:=/bin/bash -O extglob
```

The `extglob` option is not set by default, so you have to do that yourself.