# How do I fix a "syntax error near unexpected token `('" when using '!(...)' in Makefile?

Tags: bash, shell, syntax, makefile, wildcard

I have a `Makefile` as follows:

```
test:
    rm -rf !(.git|folder1|folder2)
```

Upon running `make test`, everything in the folder must get deleted except for `.git/`, `folder1/`, and `folder2/`.

Instead, I get the following error:

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `rm -rf !(.git|folder1|folder2)'
make: *** [test] Error 2
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `!(...)` wildcard syntax only works if the `extglob` shell option is set (`shopt -s extglob`). This option is not enabled by default.

An alternative way to do this is:

```
find '(' -name .git -o -name folder1 -o -name folder2 ')' -prune -o -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: Not only that but you have to be using bash as your shell.  The default POSIX shell does not support `extglob`.  If you want your makefile to rely on the presence of bash, then you should add `SHELL := /bin/bash` into it otherwise make won't use it.

Comment: Despite enabling extglob, I still get the error that the OP describes.  When I try escaping the parens, `\(`, it gives me a `No such file or directory` error.

Comment: @gdw2 How did you enable extglob? Makefiles don't use the shell options from the parent shell, they run a new shell for every line. You need to configure the shell options within the Makefile. `$ shopt -s extglob; make` won't work.

Comment: @JohnKugelman. Put the following at the top of the makefile: `SHELL:=/bin/bash -O extglob`. (source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6922447/389812).  I'm no longer getting the error that I was before.  Turns out that a later makefile import was resetting `SHELL` to be something else.

Comment: thank you so much! I am going to crash, if without finding your answer.

Comment: @gdw2 Thank you for your comment, it saved me a lot of headache.